# Unique id for Scala object

Tags: scala, object

In Python, id(x) gives the unique id of object x. What's the equivalence in Scala?

```
>>> id(True)
1166096
>>> id(False)
1166108
>>> x = id([1,2,3])
>>> id(x)
2058589988
>>> y = id([1,2,3])
>>> id(y)
2058589976
```

I could use x.hashCode for the id, but it will return the same value when the contents are the same. I'd like to know what makes `a eq b == false` in the following code. What values are compared in `a eq b`?

```
scala> val a = ArrayBuffer(1,2,3)
a: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)

scala> val b = ArrayBuffer(1,2,3)
b: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)

scala> a.hashCode
res44: Int = 387518613

scala> b.hashCode
res45: Int = 387518613

scala> a eq b
res39: Boolean = false
```

Comment: Is there some particular functionality you need out of `id` beyond what `is` or `weakref` give you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to do this. You need to generate and keep track of IDs yourself.

`eq` compares references, and is similar to `==` in Java.

There is `System.identityHashCode` (which is the default implementation of `Any.hashCode`) but it is not guaranteed to be unique.

You may be able to implement `id` using the JNI, although it might not be trivial due to the possibility of a compacting GC being in place. I don't know much about the JNI, though.

Even then, I don't see `id` as a useful function and I don't see *any* use for it. If you need a reference to an object, store a reference. If you need a weak reference, use a `java.lang.ref.WeakReference[T]`.

Comment: wow, using JNI for generating unique id's ... it is kinda microscope used as a hummer

Comment: (that wasn't me, btw)

Comment: About not seeing possible use: one could want to check if a given object already exist in a set of object 'O'. Using `eq` all you can do is always compare with all objects in 'O', linear. If one had an id, it could put it in a set, making this check linear

Answer (score 3):

> I could use x.hashCode for the id, but it will return the same value
>   when the contents are the same.

First of all: no. As per the documentation: "The default hashing algorithm is platform dependent." So do not make any assumption on hashCode.

Second: `eq` compares references. As per the documentation: "Tests whether the argument (arg0) is a reference to the receiver object (this)."

Third: you can't get the equivalent of the python id in scala.

Comment: `hashCode` *must* return the same value if the objects are equal. Of course that doesn't necessarily match up with "the contents are the same" but any implementation which does not preserve this property is incorrect.