# Checking sameness/equality in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, equality

As I asked in other post ([Unique id for Scala object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060121/unique-id-for-scala-object)), it doesn't seem like that I can have `id` just like Python.

I still need to check the sameness in Scala for unittest. I run a test and compare the returned value of some nested collection object (i.e., List[Map[Int, ...]]) with the one that I create.

However, the hashCode for mutable map is the same as that of immutable map. As a result (x == y) returns True.

```
scala> val x = Map("a" -> 10, "b" -> 20)
x: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 10, b -> 20)

scala> x.hashCode
res0: Int = -1001662700 

scala> val y = collection.mutable.Map("b" -> 20, "a" -> 10)
y: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(b -> 20, a -> 10)

scala> y.hashCode
res2: Int = -1001662700
```

In some cases, it's OK, but in other cases, I may need to make it failed test. So, here comes my question.

- Q1: What is the normally used method for comparing two values (including very complicated data types) are the same? I may compare the `toString()` results, but I don't think this is a good idea.
- Q2: Is it a general rule that mutable data structure has the same hashCode with immutable counterpart?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`AnyRef.eq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.AnyRef@eq(x$1:AnyRef):Boolean) which does reference equality (which is as close as you can get to Python's `id` function and is identical if you just want to compare *references* and you don't care about the actual ID):

```
scala> x == y
true

scala> x eq y
false
```

Comment: Well, I don't think "eq" is a possible way to use in unittests that sometimes require me I need to compare returned value with the one that I need to make on the spot.

Comment: You want to check if the returned value is equal to something you don't have access to?

Comment: Ah, so you want custom equality checks - your best bet is probably [scalactic's `TypeCheckedTripleEquals`](http://www.scalactic.org/user_guide/ConstrainedEquality)